# MVC3 Razorview Syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Can someone please tell me how to convert this to razor view syntax?

```
<%= ViewData.Model.Firms.Count > 0 ? Html.Pager(ViewData.Model.Firms.PageSize, ViewData.Model.Firms.PageNumber, ViewData.Model.Firms.TotalItemCount) : string.Empty%>
```

thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@if (Model.Firms.Count > 0)
{
    @Html.Pager(
        Model.Firms.PageSize, 
        Model.Firms.PageNumber, 
        Model.Firms.TotalItemCount
    ) 
}
```

and if you want one liners:

```
@MvcHtmlString.Create(
    Model.Firms.Count > 0 
        ? Html.Pager(
              Model.Firms.PageSize, 
              Model.Firms.PageNumber, 
              Model.Firms.TotalItemCount
        ).ToHtmlString() 
        : string.Empty
)
```

but personally I find the first far more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to simply make a helper instead that will take care of that logic, so your view can simply call @PagerTable(Model.Firms) which will figure out to write an empty string or call Html.Pager for you.